# Laravel: Consuming Internal API

Tags: laravel

I am building a API/ and frontend in the same Laravel project.

I am using both Web, and API routes with JWT Token.

Is it possible to consume the internal API, without authenticating?

As it's within the same Laravel project, authentication internally isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. When you put routes in `routes/api.php` they automatically wrapped with `auth` middleware. If you want to omit that, use `routes/web.php` file instead.

But if you want use request to call routes from inside it's better to extract api functionality to services.

Comment: So, the routes in the API routes file aren't accessible to anyone but the Laravel application?

Comment: They normally accessible for others but wrapped with the "api" middleware group.